# The algorithm behind ss2tf in Matlab

Tags: matlab, data-conversion, state-space, control-theory

There are controllable and observable forms of [canonical](http://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/Representations/SysRepTransformations/TF2SS.html) state-space  from a transfer function. 
However, when I try `ss2tf` from Matlab, I receive a different result. What sort of algorithm does Matlab use? Is there any documentation or open source implementation of it too?

```
>> a = [1 0.4 1];
>> b = [1 2 1];
>> [A,B,C,D] = tf2ss(b,a)

A =

   -0.4000   -1.0000
    1.0000         0


B =

     1
     0


C =

    1.6000         0


D =

     1
```

Comment: Did you already try `edit tf2ss` ;-)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First to keep in mind is that state representations are not unique. Different state representations can lead to the same transfer representation (they actually form an equivalence class up to pole/zero cancellations).

Here the difference is just that and nothing more. Check the following systems: they all have the same transfer function but has different C matrices (G,H different than J) but H,J are in canonical form

```
G = ss(tf(b,a))
H = ss2ss(G,rot90(eye(2)))
J = canon(H,'companion')
```

and `canon` using negative of off-diagonals the A matrix probably after balancing. Can also be a bug.

As [WG~](https://stackoverflow.com/users/181245/wg) mentioned (shameless plug I'm the author of [`harold`](https://github.com/ilayn/harold) ), in general there are much more involved algorithms for the conversion because MIMO systems require more care. I implemented a variant of Section 4.4 of W.A. Wolowich, Linear Multivariable Systems (1974). I think matlab does a similar thing but also balances (kind-of) the realization which I have yet to add.

In general, these controllable and observable forms are not well-conditioned numerically because of the companion structure. So extra care is needed if something with considerable size and seriousness.

In practice, don't use them for assessing controllability or observability other than some textbook exercises. Instead use `minreal` and work with minimal systems.

The reason why companion matrix pops up is because the roots of the real polynomial and the eigenvalues of the companion matrix formed by the coefficients of this polynomial coincide. For some historical remarks , check out this [Cleve Moler's blog post](http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2013/12/23/fiedler-companion-matrix/) about roots.

For a classical example why this is an ill-conditioned problem [here is the example from the master himself](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilkinson%27s_polynomial).

Comment: do you mean `H = ss2ss(G,rot90(eye(2)))` ?

Comment: @ar2015 Ah yes, sorry

Comment: I still should think deep about it and probably will ask more questions from you.

Comment: @ar2015 I hope I can answer them :)

Answer (score 2):

Just checked `ss2tf`, which internal functionality you wanted to know. It basically calculates poles and zeros from a state-space system and then forms the transfer function. It uses the function `ss2zp` to do this. The poles are easily determined by calculating the eigenvalues of the state matrix A. However, I actually do not really know how it calculates the zeros. Because the function. `ltipack.sszero` which calculates the zeros of a state space system is [protected](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcode.html). However, most likely it uses an algorithm similar to http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/2199-digital-control/content/sszero.m.

You can also check https://github.com/ilayn/harold/blob/master/harold/harold.py#L2162 which uses the algorithm described in http://perso.uclouvain.be/paul.vandooren/publications/MisraVV94.pdf